# jquery sortable removes other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried implementing the jquery sortable on our project if the sorting is done there should be a re-index on the items please refer to the code below:

```
 $("#data_field_table tbody").sortable({
            stop:updateRow
        }).disableSelection();

    var updateRow = function(e,ui){
        $('td.index',ui.item.parent()).each(function(i){
            var newIndex = i +1;
            $(this).html(newIndex);
        });
```

re indexing of items are ok but what after the process the hidden input on the sorted row is being removed I am not sure if it is cause by the sortable of jquery please refer to the code below:

```
<td class="index">${data.groupOrder}<input class="hiddenValue" type="hidden" name="fgDataFields[${info.index}].groupOrder" id="go${info.index}" value="${data.groupOrder}"/>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` at the end of your updateRow function.

Try:

```
var updateRow = function(e,ui){
    $('td.index',ui.item.parent()).each(function(i){
        var newIndex = i +1;
        $(this).html(newIndex);
    })};
```

EDIT:

Just reread your question and realized that this wasn't the problem. I understand now that the re-indexing is working but the hidden input is removed.

To get around that you would have to save the input and re-add id to the item after re-indexing.

Something like this:

```
var updateRow = function(e,ui){
$('td.index',ui.item.parent()).each(function(i){
    var newIndex = i +1;

    var input = $(this).find('input');

    $(this).html(newIndex);
    $(this).append(input)
})};
```